# Logo detection problems using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm working on a small project trying to detect logos in images via OpenCV. There may be many logos so that's why I tried it by following [this OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) but I can't get any good results. Pattern matching won't work because logos are from kinda natural images (so they can be rotated etc). Here are the results of a test:
[image]
Where have I gone wrong? Is this the wrong method to attempt logo detection? If so, please provide methods that should work for me and some code examples/tutorials if possible.

Comment: How is anybody supposed yo know if you are using the wrong method, if you do not tell any details? Actually this post can be considered as covered advertising....

Comment: @tobi303 Re-read the post and see the tutorial that I followed. My code is mostly identical to it. Methods used will be obvious (it's SURF based homography to put it simply).

Comment: OK, i reread the post and it just creates more questions on my side: What do you mean by: " I can't get any good results". I do not understand: "Pattern matching won't work..." , isnt this task the whole purpose of pattern matching? "Where have I gone wrong?", how are we supposed to know? I am pretty sure the tutorial is correct. If not you should write to its author.

Comment: Pattern matching works OK. But since you are using it on _untextured_ logo, your keypoints and descriptors are basically meaningless. You have better chances with [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) here

Comment: for this task better to use "shape matching" examples https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/BMP-shape.pdf

implementation can be tested with HALCON library

Comment: Please don't force us to go to 3rd party sites. Explain everything we need to know right here - in the question. Besides the mentioned alternatives, you might think about doing some preprocessing (e.g. segmentation) to isolate the logo.